How do you show something does or does not hold in finite samples?
Conformal prediction is a method in statistics/machine learning that works like the following:
We assume we have a set of exchangeable calibration scores $\mathcal{S} = \{S_1, \dots, S_n\}$, where $S_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $i$. If we rank these scores by numerical value, we can then compute the $(1-\alpha)$-empirical quantile of these scores:
\begin{equation}
\hat{q} = Q_{1-\alpha}(\mathcal{S}) = \text{the } \lceil n (1-\alpha) \rceil \text{th smallest value of } \mathcal{S}
\end{equation}
or the conservative $(1-\alpha)$-empirical quantile of these scores:
\begin{equation}
\hat{q}^{\text{cons}} = Q_{1-\alpha}^{\text{cons}}(\mathcal{S}) = \text{the } \lceil (n+1) (1-\alpha) \rceil \text{th smallest value of } \mathcal{S}.
\end{equation}
Then for any new score $S=s$ that is exchangeable with the calibration scores, we can construct the prediction set
\begin{equation}
C(s) = \{r \in \mathbb{R} : r \le \hat{q} \}
\end{equation}
or the conservative prediction set
\begin{equation}
C^{\text{cons}}(s) = \{r \in \mathbb{R} : r \le \hat{q}^{\text{cons}} \}.
\end{equation}
Then, conformal prediction literature says that by construction, the following guarantee:
\begin{equation}
\text{Prob}\{s \in C(s)\} \ge 1-\alpha
\end{equation}
holds asymptotically, while
\begin{equation}
\text{Prob}\{s \in C^{\text{cons}}(s)\} \ge 1-\alpha
\end{equation}
holds in finite samples.
I understand at a high level that the correction to make the empirical quantile more conservative somehow accounts for worst case points and therefore allows for a finite-sample guarantee. However, I find this explanation vague, and I would not be able to easily understand whether other "conservative corrections" or "finite sample corrections" lead to a finite-sample guarantee.
Could anyone explain this more concretely for me?
Reference
For more reading, see https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~ryantibs/statlearn-s23/lectures/conformal.pdf at "In this way, we can also see the solution here as simply to taking the sample quantile"

They already give a proof in the text, but I think the most concrete (IMO, of course) argument is sort of shoved into a footnote. Perhaps developing it fully would help.
Take $S_1, \cdots, S_n, S_{n+1}$ exchangeable, and for any $k \in [1:n+1],$ let $S_{(k,n+1)}$denote the $k$th largest value amongst the $S_i$s. Then $$ P(S_{n+1} > S_{(k,n+1)}) = \frac{k-1}{n+1},$$ since due to exchangeability, all  permutations of the vector $S_1^{n+1}$ are equally likely. Now, suppose that we could, using only $S_1^n$, work out an upper bound to $S_{(k,n+1)}$ - call this $U_{(k,n)}.$ Then we would also know that $$ P(S_{n+1} > U_{(k,n)}) \le \frac{k-1}{n+1},$$ since $U_{(k,n)} \ge S_{(k,n+1)}$. So now the question is what upper bound we can work out.
One guess is the $k$th largest value amongst the $S_1^n$ itself - let's call this $T_{(k,n)}$. This is close, but not quite right. Indeed, if it happened that $S_{n+1} \le T_{(k,n)},$ then in fact we'd have $T_{(k,n)} = S_{(k,n+1)},$ but if instead $S_{n+1} > T_{(k,n)},$ then we would actually have $T_{(k,n)} = S_{(k+1, n+1)} < S_{(k,n+1)},$ which would break this upper bound property. But this also suggests a simple statistic that is always an upper bound: take $T_{(k-1,n)}$ - no matter what $S_{n+1}$ is, we know that $T_{(k-1,n)} \in \{S_{(k,n+1)}, S_{(k-1,n+1)}\},$ both of which are $\ge S_{(k,n+1)}$ always. So, let us set $U_{(k,n)} = T_{(k-1,n)}$.
Now, in conformal prediction, we usually want a level $\alpha$ guarantee rather than one in terms of some $k$ parameter. But this is easy to translate: it suffices that $(k-1)/(n+1) \le \alpha \iff k - 1 \le \alpha(n+1),$ so we should take the threshold $T_{(\lfloor \alpha(n+1)\rfloor, n)},$ i.e., the $\lfloor \alpha(n+1)\rfloor$ largest of the $S_1^n$. Of course, this is also the $\lceil (1-\alpha) (n+1)\rceil$th smallest value.
Finally, you can also see the whole asymptotic guarantee business directly: suppose we instead thresholded at $T_{(k,n)}$ with $k = \lfloor \alpha n \rfloor$. Then notice that $T_{(k,n)} = U_{(k+1,n)},$ so we'd have similar guarantees but with an upper bound of $\alpha + \textrm{something}$ instead. The nice thing is that this $\textrm{something}$ is always $\le (1/n+1)$ (prove this!), so for large enough $n$ this is fine (i.e., gives you an asymptotic level $\alpha$ guarantee).
